# Which app spends all my quotas on GA profile

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've authorized multiple external applications to work with my Google Analytics API via OAUTH.

Developers of one app tells me that they have following error:

> Quota Error: profileId ga:**** has exceeded the daily request limit.

How can I find which application is spending all my quotas?

Comment: You can review your projects in the cloud console (formerly known as Google API console) https://console.cloud.google.com/, each project has an overview on API usage.

Comment: I have no direct access to application's project console in gcloud. But developers says that they cannot get usage for single profile, they see only common usage for all profiles and there is no anomalies.